# IJCADの選択状態の認識

Tags: .net, ijcad

.NETを利用してIJCAD用のアプリを開発しています。
コマンドを実行していない状態で図形を選択した際に、通知を受け取りたいのですが方法がわかりません。
AUTOCADでは、Document.ImpliedSelectionChangedイベントをフックすることで実現できました。
IJCADではどのようにすればよいのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

IJCAD の .NET API は AutoCAD の .NET API と高い互換性があるので、
基本的にはAutoCAD と同じコードで実現できると思いますよ。
（IJCADでも、Document.ImpliedSelectionChangedイベントが使えます）

それとも、IJCADで.NET APIを使って開発する環境の構築方法が分からない感じでしょうか？